# HTTP traffic through PIX VPN from outside site

Tags: squid, cisco-pix

I have a remote site with a website that only allows access from the outside IP assigned to our local PIX. I have users connecting to the local networking using a VPN that need to be able to view this remote site. I don't think this works because the packets want to come in and go out over the same (ext) interface. So I'm looking for a way to make this work using the PIX or setting up a service on a server on the local network to act as a middle-man for the HTTP requests.

The remote site doesn't support setting up a VPN to our PIX. The remote website is dishing out pages over a non-standard port.

Can I use squid or something similar to proxy just one site?

Here's some parts of the PIX config. VPN clients get assigned an IP from [vpn_subnet] and I want them to be able to access port 12345 on remote site [remote_host_ip]. One thing to note, I have users at the remote site using the VPN client to connect to our site and since that site only has one IP, they are seen by our local site as [remote_host_ip].

```
   ip local pool vpnpool <vpn_subnet_ip_range>

   tunnel-group vpn_abc type remote-access
   tunnel-group vpn_abc general-attributes
    address-pool vpnpool
    authentication-server-group (outside) AuthInbound
    default-group-policy vpn_pol_abc
   tunnel-group vpn_abc ipsec-attributes
    pre-shared-key *

   group-policy vpn_pol_abc internal
   group-policy vpn_pol_abc attributes
    wins-server value <local_ip>
    dns-server value <local_ip>
    vpn-idle-timeout 30
    split-tunnel-policy tunnelspecified
    split-tunnel-network-list value vpnusers
    default-domain value example.com

   access-list vpnusers extended permit ip <local_subnet> 255.255.0.0 <vpn_subnet> 255.255.255.0
   access-list vpnusers extended permit ip host <remote_host_ip> <vpn_subnet> 255.255.255.0

   access-list nonat extended permit ip <local_subnet> 255.255.0.0 <vpn_subnet> 255.255.255.0
   access-list nonat extended permit ip host <remote_host_ip> <vpn_subnet> 255.255.255.0

   nat (inside) 0 access-list nonat
   nat (inside) 1 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, an HTTP proxy would work, but is not required; VPN traffic coming in the outside interface can leave the outside interface just fine with no proxy needed.

If you provide configuration details, we can assist more specifically with how to do it - if users on VPN aren't able to connect to internet sites, then there's most likely an issue with either the VPN configuration, or your NAT configuration.

Comment: Just to add how to let it exit the same interface (ie outside): same-security-traffic permit intra-interface

Comment: I tried same-security-traffic but it made no difference. I have added some of my PIX config.

Comment: You'll need to NAT for the VPN clients heading to the remote site as if they were in your LAN.  Remove the `access-list nonat extended permit ip host <remote_host_ip> <vpn_subnet> 255.255.255.0` line and add `nat (outside) 1 <vpn_subnet> 255.255.255.0`.